# Crystal Lang: can't compile App with MySQL library on OSX El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan, crystal-lang

I am migrating Crystal Lang development into a new machine running OSX El-Capitan.

I have encountered a problem where when compiling an App with MySQL bindings, the crystal compiler throws this error:

```
$ crystal build src/test1.cr 
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1: `cc -o "/Users/james/cprojects/test1/test1" "${@}"  -rdynamic  -lmysqlclient -lpcre -lgc -lpthread /usr/local/Cellar/crystal-lang/0.18.7_1/src/ext/libcrystal.a -levent -liconv -ldl -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib`
```

In previous versions of OSX, All I needed to do was to so a Symbolic link and it does the trick:

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Unfortunately, El Capitan, this is impossible

```
ln: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: Operation not permitted
```

This is the contents of /usr/local/mysql/lib/ (note that now I am using v20 insted of 18)

```
libmysqlclient.20.dylib libmysqld-debug.a   mecab
libmysqlclient.a    libmysqld.a     pkgconfig
libmysqlclient.dylib    libmysqlservices.a  plugin
```

I have seen some ideas on using the install_name_tool thats specific for XCode.

Could anyone thats migrated to El Capitan shed some light? Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the system integrity protection you can't create the symlink there. But this isn't actually necessary anyways.

Just add the folder where your MySQL Library is installed to the "Library Search Paths" build setting (or if you are not using the Xcode build system add -L linker option with the path). You added "/usr/lib" and "/usr/local/lib" there, but your MySQL library is in "/usr/local/mysql/lib", so the linker can't find it.

For this situation install_name_tool is not necessary. This can change the paths the loader uses to look for the library at runtime.

Comment: Another option is to set the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. For Crystal the `-L` flag can be passed via the `--link-flags` option to `crystal build`. I wonder if it's not possible for homebrew, or whatever installed MySQL, to correct things here?